# How to implement interface?

Tags: typescript

Interface is:

```
interface b {
        (): void;
    }
```

I tried to impement this interface:

```
class A implements b {
   function(): void {
      // Body
   }
}
```

How to implement the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface b {
   setFunc: void;
}
```

```
class A implements b {
   setFunc: void = //sth function else
}
```

Check the Class interface for more information in this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible. This is a function interface.

Comment: What is purpose if `():void` what does it mean?

Comment: `let foo : b = function () { };` This interface mean that the object can be called (i.e. a function). In JavaScript class object cannot be called, that's why you cannot implement this interface on a class.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types